# Changing the position of a SKTileMapNode doesn't change the location of it's rows and columns

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift-playground

So I have a TileMap that I created programatically in a playground.
I changed it's position because it appears at the bottom left of the view.
Then I created a SpriteNode that I positioned at the top left of the map, using centerOfTile(atColumn:, Row:).

but then the sprite appears at the location of top left tile of the map **before** it was moved.

Any idea how I should proceed to update the centerOfTiles location?

here's how the code looks like:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let heroNode = SKSpriteNode(color: .blue, size: testMap.tileSize)
    heroNode.zPosition = testMap.zPosition + 1
    heroNode.position = testMap.centerOfTile(atColumn: 9, row: 9)
    self.addChild(heroNode)

    for x in 1...testMap.numberOfColumns {
        for y in 1...testMap.numberOfRows {
            let tileG = (x+y)%2 == 0 ? testGrassTileGroup : testGrass2TileGroup
            testMap.setTileGroup(tileG, forColumn: x, row: y)
        }
    }
    self.addChild(testMap)
    testMap.position = CGPoint(x: 170, y: 150)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

[The live view result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M753.png)

[The live view of the sprite appearing as intended when I leave the tile map in it original place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6dQ8.png)

Comment: Moving the `heroNode` set-up after `testMap.position = ...` didn't work?

Comment: @bg2b Yeah I tried that but it didn't work no

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the node as child of the map instead of a child of the View